# XAML Style Won't Apply Until EventTrigger Command Completes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox which defines a custom ControlTemplate. The selected item has a style that changes the background and foreground, and the style basically works. However, I want to introduce a behaviour that displays a modal message box on selection changed, asking the user if they really want to select a different item. I've implemented an ICommand to do this which in the code below is shown as AreYouSureCommand.

The problem is whilst that modal message box is shown, the background style for the selected item is changed but the foreground is not. As soon as I dismiss the modal message box, the foreground colour changes. I haven't included the code for the ICommand because it's a bit convoluted but hopefully it is sufficient to say that a Window is opened with ShowDialog when it is executed.

Can anybody shed any light on why my background colour changes but not my foreground colour?

```
<ListBox x:Name="SubMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                        Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="Presenter">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <!-- Setter on MainBorder applies before AreYouSureCommand completes -->
                                <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                <!-- Setter on Presenter applies after AreYouSureCommand completes -->
                                <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AreYouSureCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SubMenu}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: If you change the order in the XAML happens the opposite?

Comment: Interesting idea, but no - if I reverse the order, the same thing happens - the background colour changes but the foreground doesn't change until I dismiss the modal message box.

Comment: I guess you´re setting the foreground to a specific value in your data template and the trigger can´t change it. Try removing the `Foreground` property and add it as default style inside the style tag for your ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came to a solution for this. Basically I use another setter for the `IsSelected` property to push the value of `IsSelected` for the `ListViewItem` onto the view model. Then I use a `DataTrigger` instead of a regular Trigger to set the selected styles, and bind the trigger to the `IsSelected` property on the view model rather than the property of the `ListViewItem` itself. I don't really know why this works - it shouldn't be any different really, but it does work.

Thanks Juan and Ben for your comments.

```
<ListBox x:Name="SubMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                        Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="Presenter">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AreYouSureCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SubMenu}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```